# Seasonality in Time Series

Tags: statistics

I have a 5 year time serie with product sales per month. I wanna know if the serie have seasonality. I decompose the serie and have this:[image]

The blue line is my time serie, black line is the seasonal component, green line is the trend component and orange line is the random component. As you  can see, the seasonal component indicates a peak in March and May of each year but this is not clear expressed in the time series(blue line). Can I assume my seasonal months are March and May just by the pattern of my seasonal component?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much about having seasonal months. It's about the length of your repeating pattern. In your black line, seasonal graph, there is a repeating downward sloping pattern that contains 5 points each time. This is your "seasonality".

The length of time it take to go fro one peak to the next is the length os your "season".

It sort of looks like the length is 12 months (e.g. May to May) but you should check. The conclusion would be something like "I have a 5-month season from May to September, that repeats every year."